# Multiprocessing of summing 2 lists doesn't work in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The sum of `sum1` and `sum2` must be equal to `499500` in the end of this code, but it prints `0`, why?

```
import multiprocessing

sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
def list_append_1(out_list):
    global sum1
    for i in out_list:
        sum1 += i
    print "sum1: ", sum1

def list_append_2(out_list):
    global sum2
    for i in out_list:
        sum2 += i
    print "sum2: ", sum2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lista_1 = [i for i in xrange(500)]# Number of random numbers to add
    lista_2 = [i for i in xrange(500,1000)]
    procs = 2   # Number of processes to create

    # Create a list of jobs and then iterate through
    # the number of processes appending each process to
    # the job list
    jobs = []
    process_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append_1, args=(lista_1,))
    process_2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append_2, args=(lista_2,))
    jobs.append(process_1)
    jobs.append(process_2)

    # Start the processes (i.e. calculate the random number lists)
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

    # Ensure all of the processes have finished
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print sum1 + sum2
```

Comment: processes are not threads, and do not share memory

Comment: the variables are global and defined before the processes are started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because each of the tasks that you run using `multiprocessing.Process` end up with their own copy of the `sum1` and `sum2` variables, along with a third copy held by the parent process. This is one of the limitations of using processes instead of threads; memory isn't shared between the processes by default. You can get the sums back by using a `multiprocessing.Queue` to send the sums to the parent process:

```
import multiprocessing

def list_append(out_list, q):
    my_sum = sum(out_list)
    print "sum: ", my_sum
    q.put(my_sum)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lista_1 = [i for i in xrange(500)]# Number of random numbers to add
    lista_2 = [i for i in xrange(500,1000)]
    procs = 2   # Number of processes to create

    # Create a list of jobs and then iterate through
    # the number of processes appending each process to
    # the job list
    jobs = []
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    process_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append, args=(lista_1, q))
    process_2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=list_append, args=(lista_2, q))
    jobs.append(process_1)
    jobs.append(process_2)

    # Start the processes (i.e. calculate the random number lists)
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

    total = q.get() + q.get()

    # Ensure all of the processes have finished        
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print total
```

Output:

```
sum1:  124750
sum2:  374750
499500
```

Comment: And as a bonus, those ugly `global` statements are gone.

Comment: @dano so, `multiprocessing.Queue()` is just an array where you store some values?

Comment: @alwbtc Its described in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) . It basically just a like a normal [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), except it has internal plumbing that will transfer any picklable Python object you `put` into the queue between processes launched via `multiprocessing.Process` and `multiprocessing.Pool`, via a `multiprocessing.Pipe`. That way, you can `put` an object into the `Queue` in one process, and `get` it from another.

Comment: I admire knowledgeable people. Seeing these answers&comments motivate me to work harder. Thanks

Comment: @dano: Re `get` before `join`.  Call me superstitious, but I'd do *both* `.get` calls before joining either process.  Depending on timing, your code could be trying to join the first process *before* the `.get` call that retrieves the result of that process.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes, that's true. We're not likely to deadlock unless the sum being returned is enormous, but I guess it could happen. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @alwbtc No problem. One other edit I just made; since we got rid of the global `sum1` and `sum2`, there's really no need to have two separate functions for adding up the numbers. Both do the exact same thing: calculate the sum of a list, and stick it in a queue. I've edited my answer to just use a the same worker function for `multiprocessing.Process` objects.

Comment: By the way, does this code above will take shorter time than summing all numbers (1 to 1000) at once? Does it take advantage of multiprocessing?

Comment: @alwbtc It *can* take advantage of multiple processes, because each `sum` operation is running in a separate process. That means the OS can dedicate two different CPU cores to doing the calculations simultaneously. That doesn't actually guarantee that will happen, though. If the lists you're passing to each process aren't particularly long, a single CPU might be able to do the work fast enough that multiple CPUs don't get used. (continued...)

Comment: @alwbtc It's also possible that the overhead of starting up two processes, then copying the data contained in each list to those two processes, and then copying the results back to the main process, ends up adding more overhead time than the amount of time you save by calculating the two sums concurrently. I would guess that summing 1-1000 this way ends up being slower than just doing it in a single process.

Comment: How do I **FORCE** the OS dedicate two different cores to do the calculations simultaneously? Does OS know better which is more advantageous? When only 1 core is dedicated, then the 2nd process will be started after 1st one is completed, right? Then of what use is multiprocessing in this case?

Comment: @alwbtc The OS is completely in control of what code gets executed against which CPU. Python has no say. What you *can* be sure of though, is that if you send two long-running CPU-bound tasks off two separate processes, the OS *will* use two cores to process both simultaneously. The only reason both would run on a single CPU is that the processing you're doing is completed so quickly that the OS doesn't get a chance to run them concurrently. (continued...)

Comment: @alwbtc In your example, you call `j.start()` in a loop. It's possible that in the time it takes Python to call start() on process 1, then loop around and call it again for process 2, process 1 might be done with its work, so the same CPU can be used for both.

Comment: Is it possible to start both these 2 processes at the same time, instead of in a loop?

Comment: @alwbtc They'll probably run closer to the exact same time if you use a `multiprocessing.Pool` instead of `Process` directly, since you won't have the overhead of actually starting the second process after the first task begins. But if the tasks are so fast that they could only run on one core, we're only taking about differences of a few tenths of a second. I wouldn't worry about it too much.